# Author permalink

Tags: permalinks, users, author, slug

I have changed my permalink "author". Now your slug is "user". But the user page slug is also "user".

How can I make sure there is no conflict between both slugs?

I hope help, please! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make sure you have a unique base for your author permalinks.  This sample code would do what you need. You may need to flush the rules after you include this code in your functions.php. A rewrite rules inspector plugin will help you get this all working smoothly:

```
    function wpse263881_init() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'author';
        $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base . '/%author%';
    }
    add_action('init', 'wpse263881_init');
```

Comment: the problem is:
There are author'post info links on the web. The permalink was author, but was redirected to the permalink of user page.

I want the author's permalink and the user's page to be the same. So, I changed the permalink of the author.

Now in the box of author info, the permalinks is "user" but does not redirect the page user, porqe its permalink is "user" too. And there is no redirection